# Angular rxjs How can I invalidate a cache?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using

```
private readData = (api: string): any => {
        if (!this.cacheService.readFromCache(api)) {
            this.cacheService.writeToCache(api, this.request(api, RequestMethod.Get)
                .map(response => {
                    return response;
                })
                .publishReplay(1)
                .refCount());
        }
        return this.cacheService.readFromCache(api);
    }
```

this piece of code to store my api call responses.  This works well but I want to expire the cache after certain amount of time since the last actual http call. Otherwise, the user would always see the "stale" cache.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this ?

```
const cacheStore=()=>{
let _cache={data:'init'}
const store=Rx.Observable.create(obs=>{
  obs.next(_cache)
})

const update=(cache)=>{
  _cache=Object.assign({},cache)
}
return {store,update}
}

const cache=cacheStore()
cache.store.subscribe(console.log)
cache.update({data:"new data"})
cache.store.subscribe(console.log)
```